# Full path in glob in Zsh

Tags: files, zsh, glob

Say I run the following on `/some/path`:

```
for x in foo/*; do
print $x
done
```

Are there any parameters I can use to tell Zsh to print, not just the filename, but the full absolute path to `$x`? (without explicitly hard-coding `/some/path` in the `print` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for x (foo/*(:A)) print -r $x
```

Or:

```
for x (foo/*) print -r $x:A
```

Though in this case:

```
print -rl foo/*(:A)
```

is enough.

`:A` expands symbolic links. You can also use `:a` which doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `a` [history expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) in a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters).

```
for x in foo/*; do
    print -r $x(:a)
done
```

With `:A` instead of `:a`, symbolic links are expanded.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepend the path to the pattern, `$x` will expand to the full path:

```
for x in /some/path/foo/*; do
  print $x
done
```

But I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for?

If you don't want to hardcode `/some/path` and you want the code always to look in the current directory, use $PWD:

```
for x in $PWD/foo/*; do
  print $x
done
```